# md5 hashing using password as salt?

Tags: php, hash, md5

```
md5($password.md5($password))
```

is this good enough for password hashing? I am not asking for comparing this to something like bcrypt.

if it is not secure, tell me why.

Comment: `md5($password.md5($id))`, is any better?

Comment: Yes, @wiiman, using the user's id as the salt is much better. I'll expand my answer a bit.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 33):

The reason to use a different salt for each user's password is so that an attacker can't take a list of all the hashed passwords and see if any of them match the hash of something easy like "password" or "12345". If you were to use the password itself as salt, then an attacker could calculate `md5("12345".md5("12345"))` and see if it matched any entries.

As I understand it, there are four levels of hashing you can use on a password table:

1. **None** - store the password as plain text. If someone gets a copy of your database, they have access to all accounts. Plain text is bad, 'mkay?
2. **Hash the password** - store the hash of the password, and throw away the real password. If someone gets a copy of your database, they can't see any passwords, only hashes. *However*, if any users have used weak passwords, then their hashes will appear in rainbow tables. For example, if a user has the password "password", then an md5 hash stored in the database would be "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99". If I look up that hash in a rainbow table like [the one at gromweb.com](http://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99), it spits out "password".
3. **Use a salt value** - choose a large random string like a GUID and store it in your configuration file. Append that string to every password before calculating a hash. Now the rainbow table is far less likely to work because it probably won't have an entry for "password59fJepLkm6Gu5dDV" or "picard59fJepLkm6Gu5dDV". Although precalculated rainbow tables are not as effective anymore, you can still be susceptible if the attacker knows your salt value. The attacker can calculate the hash of a weak password plus your salt and see if *any user in your database* uses that weak password. If you've got several thousand users, then each hash calculation lets the attacker make several thousand comparisons. How you actually use the salt may depend on the encryption algorithm you're using. For simplicity, just imagine it as appending the salt and the password together.
4. **Use a distinct salt value** - now you take something distinct like the user name, e-mail address, or even user id, and combine that with the password and the large random string from your configuration file before you calculate the hash. Now an attacker who knows your salt still has to recalculate the hash for every user to see if they have used a weak password like "password".

For more details, check out the Coding Horror post, "[You're probably storing passwords incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)".

Comment: in case of random salt, what prevents an attacker from calculating `md5("12345".md5("54321random"))`?

Comment: what part of your answer belongs to the particular OP?

Comment: In my opinion, @Col. the OP's suggested technique of `md5($password.md5($password))` is roughly as hard to break as my option 3, but more expensive for the server because it requires two md5 calculations for every log in. I think it's as hard to break as option 3 because an attacker who knows the algorithm can calculate a hash for a weak password and then compare it to the hashed password of every user.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about the attacker calculating in your first comment, @Col. If you're asking what makes option 3 harder to break than option 2, it's just that option 2 can be attacked with precalculated rainbow tables and doesn't require as much work from the attacker.

Comment: so, you're talking of coincidence of some lame passwords, right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "coincidence of some lame passwords", @Col. I'm assuming that an attacker has access to all information about the system except the actual user passwords. As well, a list of the billion most likely passwords sorted by frequency and a precalculated rainbow table for the million most likely passwords. None of the possibilities I laid out make it impossible to extract one of the passwords, but each one increases the _processing time_ required for the attacker to find a password.

Comment: @Col: You should salt your passwords, and it should be with a distinct value that's stored in cleartext or as part of the hashed value. Not sure what your problem is here.

Comment: @Adam I have not a single problem. It's Don who has it.

Comment: @Don Kirby, "processing time" is not really a huge deal for handling a transaction like logging in. Which doesn't actually occur that often to begin with.  Actually, this post mentions some interesting benefits to having longer authentication time. http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Kenny. When I said processing time, I was referring to the processing time of the attacker, not the server doing authentication. But your point about the *advantages* of an expensive encryption algorithm is a good one.

Answer (score 4):

Although it seems quite enough to me, it will be in danger in case if someone precomputed a rainbow table based on the same algorithm (what is quite possible).
So, I'd rather use an email for the salt which seems pretty secure yet usable. Paranoids may *add* some constant site-wide salt.

People often makes too big deal out of password salt (in theory), while in their applications they allow simple passwords and transfer them in plain text over insecure HTTP in practice.

Every freakin' day I see questions regarding salt or hash.
And not a single one regarding password complexity. While

## The only your concern should be password complexity.

Why? Let me show you.

**extraordinary good salt + weak password = breakable in seconds**

It is always assumed that salt is known to attacker. So, by using some dictionary of most used passwords and adding [whatever extra-random-super-long] salt to them, a weak password can be discovered in seconds. Same goes for brute-forcing short passwords.

**just sensible salt + strong password = unbreakable**

Quite unique salt makes precomputed tables useless and good password makes both dictionary and brute-force attacks good for nothing.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Concerning your last remark: good point. But intercepting a single password is hardly as problematic as getting the whole table. Unless of course the sniffer is listening at the gates, in stead of at the coincidental users end.

Comment: Randomized salt is the way to go, and used by most worthy password management scheme. A simple 16 bit random salt makes rainbow table 65536 times more expensive to compute and to store...

Comment: @Bruno the salt proposed by the OP is 128 bit quite random one. What's wrong with it? What's **particularly** wrong?

Comment: The OP propose a slat dependant on the password, not a random one. That's actually not a salt at all. Say I want to store all hash for 4 lower case letters passwords  : his proposal costs me only 4^26*128 bits as each password can only lead to one hash. With a 16 bits seed it would cost me 2^16 as much disk space as each user password can now have 2^16 hashes representing it. Going to 32 bits salt you make Rainbow Tables almost impossible to store, and very long to compute even throwing lots of hardware at the problem.

Comment: @Bruno it's indeed a salt, even being not so random. With good strong password it will be quite enough while with weak password no super-extra-random salt will help against dictionary/brute-force.

Comment: It's not in his scheme there is a 1<->1 relation between passwords and their disk representation. With a random salt with n possible salts there is a 1<->n relation between passwords and their disk representation, making it much more expensive to pre-compute hashs.

Comment: @Bruno you're talking of coincident passwords?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do much against dictionary attacks, only twice as hard to compute a dictionary versus a single `md5`, and `md5` is pretty cheap these days.

Comment: not really. it's not any harder to compute the dictionary with a fixed salt or your method. same complexity.

Comment: same goes for the random salt, isn't it?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: No, because then you'd have to try every word against the unique salt, per password, which makes it a much more labor intensive game. With a single known salt, you'd only have to create a dictionary once.

Comment: but it's not single known salt. all these salts are different!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I think there's some miscommunication here. You may have misunderstood me. I think we're talking about the same thing. Single known salt for all passwords = worse. Unique salt per password = better.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is not secure in itself because it is partially broken (collisions) and is too small of a digest anyway. If one doesn't want to use a proper password derivation function à la bcrypt, scrypt or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) you should at least use SHA-256 for new designs (and have a plan to migrate to SHA-3 when it will be out, so be sure to store the scheme you used to hash the password with the result, so both scheme can coexist as you use the new hashing procedure when people change passwords).

If you intend to sell your program using MD5 in any capacity can be a show stopper for most government sales (e.g. in the US algorithms used must be FIPS 140-2 approved and many other countries got the same kind of requirements).

Comment: I was always curious, What collosions can do with salted passwords? (if you even ever find one)

Comment: Nothing from a current knowledge point of view. Collision attacks don't necessarily translate as a pre-image attacks, however their mere existence show the design is broken. One part of the contract of a cryptographic hash function is broken, so you cannot trust it anymore. Continuing to use MD5 is like drinking in a glass with a crack, you may be perfectly ok yet it could also shatter in your hand sending you to the emergency room.

Comment: I can imagine broken glass scenario. But I have no idea what particular scenario can be in case of hashing function. Can you elaborate a bit? Or you don't know but being cautious just in case?

Comment: Cautious just in case, you have a collection of glasses, why drink in the one with a crack when a pristine ones are next to it. The trust in a cryptographic hash is shattered the moment a single practical attack is found. And frankly switching hash algorithm is usually a matter of changing one call, so why go with the lesser option?

Comment: just to be a programmer, not worshiper. Being a programmer, I want to understand, what is particularly wrong with my glass.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why random password salt is recommended for hashing password, so that an attacker who knows the password hash can't compare it to [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) of pre-calculated hashed from dictionary.

If you're using password as salt, attacker can pre-calculate hashes of $word.md5($word) first from their dictionary

Comment: what's the difference between such pre-calculation and calculation itself?

Answer (score 1):

With your solution you pretty much defeats the purpose of using a salt against precomputed dictionary attacks.

With a precomputed dictionary, as the name implies, someone has already created a table of hashes (the computed `md5` result) for particular words, ahead of time.

Consider this table `hashtable` (with imaginary hashes, just for illustration purposes)

```
word | hash
------------
foo  | 54a64
bar  | 3dhc5
baz  | efef3
```

Testing these values against your table, could be as simple as:

```
SELECT h.word
FROM hashtable h, yourtable y
WHERE y.password = MD5( CONCAT( h.word, h.hash ) );
```

With a match, you'ld have the password.

However, if you did NOT hash the password, before concatenating it again with the password and hashing it once more, it would be more difficult to attack it with a pre-computed dictionary. Because then the password would be for instance `md5( 'testtest' )` which makes the precomputed table worthless, if the precomputed table has only taken into account single instances of the word.

You can easily see that it gets even more difficult if you did not use the password as a salt, but used another random string as salt. And it gets even more difficult still, when you create unique salts for every passwords. Of course, if you create unique salts per password, you'd have to save the salt in a separate column along with the passwords in a database row.

So my advice would be:

```
md5( 'uniquesalt' . 'password' );
```

Or actually, don't use `md5` at all, but use the far better `sha1`, `sha256` (or higher) hashing algorithms.

Comment: your query is the same as calculating a hash for the every possible variant. how it's differ from brute-force?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: you have good point there. It admittedly is not very much different, except that you don't have to hash twice, which would probably win you some time. Not much perhaps. But my main point was to illustrate that a precomputed table probably usually only considers single words. And doesn't take into account concatenated words that are hashed.