# Best way to store "backup codes" for two-factor authentication?

Tags: database, security, web-applications, two-factor-authentication

I'm implementing a two-factor authentication system for one of my side projects and would like to institute some "one time codes", much like Google has for their two-factor authentication.

My question is, what would be the safest way to store these codes on the server? Do they need to be encrypted in the database? Would I use something like bcrypt to has them the same way I hash passwords? I would think that might be overkill considering an attacker would know each hash represents a 6 digit number which would bring brute force times down to almost nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Think of your one time codes (OTCs) as passwords. Now use security best practices for managing passwords.

Also, you should NOT use 6 digit numbers as OTCs. Like I said, these are (equivalent to) passwords and you do NOT want these passwords to be weak.

Please refer to [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) for more information on how to securely store passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague but here are some pointers:

1. Storing at least one part of the authentication on a separate machine reduces the risk of both parts being compromised together.
2. **Salt your hashes!** The salt may be unique to your site or unique to the user as long as you can re-create it when you want to verify.

   - Why salt? The md5hash of the string `123456` is `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` - as you said, easily brute forced. But what if I add the user's id? You can add it to the hash and re-hash or add it to the original text so: md5hash of `123456aneroid` is `74821b76b332b28532136eb58e1b7f40`.
   - Other addtional salts can also be used, see this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482545/1431750
3. The database should store these [salted hashes](http://www.google.com/search?q=salt+hash).
4. One of your salts could be derived from the 2nd credential.
5. You can re-hash the hash multiple times.