# Password encryption login problems

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, authentication

Im having problem looking up and verifying a user's encrypted password in my sql database. The registration process is fine, it creates their row with their md5 ecrypted password but then when trying to log in, it won't recognize their password. Heres what im using:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername = $_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='md5($mypassword)'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "$myusername";
```

Comment: `md5(...)` is being treated as literally the characters `md5(`. Also, do not use MD5. Please. Use bcrypt or something similar.

Comment: use password = md5($mypassword) as @Blender said

Comment: md5(password) = '$mypassword' will also work

Comment: from security perspective maybe you need to add SALT with your password(or switch to bcrypt) .. you can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482437/md5-hashing-using-password-as-salt

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. Unfortunately I have not found a solution to my current method. I will look into using another method such as bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername = $_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM '".$tbl_name.". WHERE username='".$myusername."' and password='".md5($mypassword)."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = $myusername;
```

Comment: i have same problem and i make changes as you suggest but its still not working. can you help me?

Comment: @JohnR what is the exact problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978275/android-login-authentication-with-remote-mysql-database check this link.

Answer (score 0):

replace your $sql with following. I assume you have correct table name in $tbl_name -variable.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE username='".$myusername."' and password='".md5($mypassword)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

lol your code is to complicated, ill provide scripts i made!

Using STMT means NO SQL INJECTION

How to encrypt your password (THE CORRECT WAY!!!)

```
function Encrypt($text) {
  $cost = 12;
  $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
  $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
  $altered_text = crypt($text, $salt);
  return $altered_text;
}

// Then use the code below to use the function

$password = Encrypt($password);
```

In your login please use brute force protection

Here is a Brute Force Protection Code

```
function BruteForce($user_id, $link) {
    $now = time();
    $timespan = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$timespan'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Then use the sql statement below

```
CREATE TABLE `login_attempts` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `time` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Then to store an attempt

```
function StoreAttempt($user_id, $link) {
    $now = time();
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO login_attempts (user_id, time) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $a, $b);
    $a = $user_id;
    $b = $now;
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Then to use it in action

```
// user_id = the users id after you get the users id
// link = the database connection

if (BruteForce($user_id, $link) === true) {
    // Too many login attempts
} else {
    // Store Attempt
    StoreAttempt($user_id, $link);
}
```

I suggest you use a secure session instead of a plain one

Use the code below

```
function SecureSession() {
    $session_name = 'SecureSession';
    $secure = true;
    $httponly = true;
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        die("Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    }
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start(); 
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

To start the session now

```
SessionSecure();
```

If you plan on using PHP SELF

Use this code below

```
function SanitizeUrl($url) {
    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }
    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url); 
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;
    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }
    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);
    $url = htmlentities($url);
    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);
    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

The function above is protection against PHP SELF ex

Then to use it

```
SanitizeUrl($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Now for the actual login function

I suggest using email then username in your login mainly because your email is not unique!

```
function Login($email, $password, $link) {
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        // A field is empty
        return false;
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`username`,`password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";
        if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($db_id, $db_username, $db_password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                if (BruteForce($db_id, $link) === false) {
                    $password = Encrypt($password);
                    if ($password == $db_password) {
                        // LOGGED IN, SET SESSION VARS
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // Store Attempt
                        StoreAttempt($user_id, $link);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in action

```
SessionSecure();

if (isset($_POST['DoLogin'])) {
   $email = $_POST['login-email'];
   $password = $_POST['login-password'];
   if (Login($email, $password, $link) === true) {
       // Logged in Redirect now!
   } else {
       // Login failed
   }
}
```

Feel free to use this code!!! :)