# Ajax reveal call when click button

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

So I have this page that lists a few devices and I need an inventory of device/password for everything.
I made a page, I have a reveal button etc.
What is not clear to me is how I can display the password as "**********" at the beginning and on click to call a php function through ajax that makes the query and then replace the "***********" with the actual password.

Here's what I got until now:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($passwords)) {
        echo '<ul class="list-group">';
        foreach ($passwords as $password) {
            echo '<li class="list-group-item">';
            echo "<p>Name: $password->name</p>";
            echo "<p>Details: $password->details</p>";
            echo '<button type="button" name="' . $password->ID . '" class="btn-xs btn btn-theme">Reveal</button>' . "<span class='pass_hidder'>********</span></li>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li class="list-group-item">Name: No password set</li>';
    }
?>
```

I'm not too good with ajax so I'm not really sure what to do next.
I've found a few useful posts before asking but not exactly what I was hoping.
Any hint will be very useful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add Salt or encrypt the password variable so that you may not reveal its real value but on your back-end, you can always reveal its real value and do your query. The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482437/md5-hashing-using-password-as-salt) question will help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Security should not really be an issue bcause it's an internal password management idea but you are right on the other side, you can never be too careful :)

Comment: You cannot display your variable which is '1234abcd' to '********'. If you don't want it to be known publicly, add salt on it or encrypt it.

Comment: I was thinking to make an ajax call and display the result when you click on button.